# Get count of intersected rows on the same table

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have the following table:

```
ID  user_id          skill_id        
1   8                1    
2   8                3     
3   2                3        
4   5                3          
5   2                1          
6   5                2
7   5                4
8   5                5
9   8                5
```

I need to get the count of users who have **both** skills 1 and 3 (or more), a real life example would be to get the count of users who know php,mysql,and javascript, but not those that only know php and javascript.

When I do `SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) WHERE skill_id IN(1,3)` I get a count of 3, which means it's giving me the users with any of them, I need the users who have all?

As a side note I think I could do this intersecting different queries but that would mean a separated query for each tag and there can be endless combinations of skills, something tells me there is a simpler way, speed is really important here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain those users use

```
SELECT user_id
FROM `table`
WHERE skill_id IN(1,3)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING 2 = COUNT(*)
```

If there is no unique constraint for `(user_id, skill_id)`, use `COUNT (DISTINCT skill_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

To obtain only the count of those users you may use the above query as a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ( SELECT user_id
       FROM `table`
       WHERE skill_id IN(1,3)
       GROUP BY user_id
       HAVING 2 = COUNT(*) 
     ) AS `table`
```

Comment: This almost works, it gives me the users that have all the selected skills but it doesn't give me a COUNT, `SELECT COUNT(user_id)
FROM \`table\`
WHERE skill_id IN(1,3)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING 2 = COUNT(*)`  gives me a lots of rows that have the same value, Also this means that if I want 3 skills I have to change it to `HAVING 3 = COUNT(*)`

Comment: @ccrez answer updated.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!, hope this ends up being helpful to other people, I up-voted your answer but it says it wont show cause I don't have enough reputation :(